# import library to arduino

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

I want to import a library that I found in the internat to arduino nano. I followed [this](https://www.arduino.cc/en/hacking/libraries) tutorial. I downloaded the test library (in the tutorial) and the test library didn't appear in the "include library" list.

How can I import this library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be in the directory where are your sketches located (this is configurable in Preferences). There'll be subdirectory named `library` and the new library must be in its own subdirectory. And you have to restart Arduino IDE.

But for the last several releases there is also possibility to `Add ZIP Library` and it'll do all this work for you:

[image]